# JWT Refresh token Angular

Tags: angular, oauth, jwt, refresh-token

I am not sure this is the right forum for this.In my angular application, I want to implement refresh token scenario. but we are thinking of two different approaches.

1. we should refresh the token only when we received 401 error from the server and make a call to the api and get the new set of tokens.
2. we should set a timer in angular application that refreshes the token after certain time.
   I am not sure which path we should take? I have tried to analyze it I feel we need to take approach one. but I am reaching out to experts to understand the advantages of one over the other?

Comment: This question will probably lead to opinionated answers, but I would take step 2. That's where the expiration date is for. Refresh it maybe 5 seconds before it expires, so you are not to late with the refresh. 401 should mean you are not authorized, not that you forgot to refresh the token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for it save token with the expire date now in app.comp.ts match current date with expire date if its passes expire date then refresh in other case refresh token